# How do I change one of my limit $-\infty$ to $\infty$ to evaluate this Integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

**I'm trying to  evaluate:**

$$\Large{\int_0^1 x^m \ln^n (x)\mathrm{dx}}$$

$$y=-\ln x \implies x=e^{-y} $$

$$dy/dx=1/x \implies dx=x dy= e^{-y} dy$$

$$ - \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{-(m+1)y} (-1)^n y^n \mathrm{dy}$$

$$u=(m+1)y \implies du=dy$$

**I Know how to solve this, If only I could changed the lower limit of $-\infty$ to $\infty$, how do I change that?**

*I hope you see I can't do the obvious $s=-u$ because I'm trying to use the Gamma function, so please don't suggest that or $u=-(m+1)y$*

Comment: What about $u \mapsto \dfrac{1}{u}$?

Comment: @GabrielH how will I make use of the Gamma function by doing so, since Il end up with the term being $e^{u^{-1}}$ Instead of the desired $e^{-u}$ ?

Comment: Ah, I suppose it would not work then ...

Comment: @GabrielH Yep it won't :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Substitute $x=e^{-u}$:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1x^m\log(x)^n\,\mathrm{d}x
&=(-1)^{n+1}\int_\infty^0u^ne^{-(m+1)u}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=(-1)^n\int_0^\infty u^ne^{-(m+1)u}\,\mathrm{d}u
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4):

For a variety :

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 x^m \ln^n (x)\mathrm{dx} &=\int_0^1 \frac{\partial^n}{\partial m^n}x^m\mathrm{dx} \\~\\
&= \frac{\partial^n}{\partial m^n}\int_0^1x^m\mathrm{dx} \\~\\
&= \frac{\partial^n}{\partial m^n}\dfrac{1}{m+1} \\~\\
&= \dfrac{(-1)^nn!}{(m+1)^{n+1}} \\~\\
  \end{align}$$

---

This is actually a classic problem! For using Gamma function, $x = e^{\frac{-u}{m+1}}$ substitution works smoothly. See [Sophomore's_dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream)

Answer (score 3):

I just want to mention that ususal integration by parts also works, and you don't need anything fancy like $\Gamma$-Functions or Feynman's trick. Let's see:

$$
I(m,n)=\int_0^1x^m\ln^n(x)=\underbrace{\frac{n}{m+1}x^{m+1}\ln^n(x)\big|_0^1}_{=0}+\frac{n}{m+1}\int_0^1x^m\ln^{n-1}(x)
$$

Integrating again by parts, we see what happens

$$
I(m,n)=\underbrace{\frac{n}{(m+1)^2}x^{m+1}\ln^{n-1}(x)\big|_0^1}_{=0}-(-)^2\frac{n (n-1)}{(m+1)^2}\int_0^1x^m\ln^{n-2}(x)
$$

It's now obvious that this process repeats until the power of the logatrithm is brought down to one because than its derivative is just $1/x$, and the resulting integral will not vanish at the endpoints.  We get
$$
I(m,n)=\underbrace{\frac{(n-1)!}{(m+1)^{n}}x^{m+1}\ln(x)\big|_0^1}_{=0}-(-)^{n+1}\frac{n!}{(m+1)^n}\int_0^1x^m=(-1)^n\frac{n!}{(m+1)^{n+1}}
$$